# How do i make this query more simple

Tags: c#, database, insert

Is there a way to insert this data into access's table?
I use this code but I search about way to insert the same data into same columns.
How can I do that ?

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO lab ([lname],dtnow,wbc,rbc,hb,hcv,[Field1],[Field2],[Field3],a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,hh) VALUES (@lname,@dtnow,@wbc,@rbc,@hb,@hcv,@f1,@f2,@f3,@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n,@o,@p,@q,@r,@s,@t,@u,@v,@w,@x,@y,@z,@aa,@bb,@cc,@dd,@ff,@rr,@hh)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", age.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtnow", dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wbc", age1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rbc", age2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hb", age3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hcv", age4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", age5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", age6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", age7.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", age8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", age9.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", age10.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", age11.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", age12.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", age13.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", age14.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", age15.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", age16.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", age17.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", age18.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", age19.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", age20.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", age21.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@o", age22.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", age23.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", age24.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@r", age25.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", age26.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", age27.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", age28.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", age29.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@w", age30.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", age31.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", age32.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", age33.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aa", age34.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bb", age35.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cc", age36.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dd", age37.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ff", age38.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rr", age39.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hh", age40.Text);
```

Please don't care about `age1, age2, age3, ..., agen` they are just for testing.

Comment: What's wrong with this query?

Comment: nothing its working perfect, but is there any way to make it simple or Abbreviated

Comment: It seems to be as simple as you can make it while still being easy to read. You have however many values that you need to use in the query, and the corresponding parameters for them. By the way your dtnow field should probably be a datetime field type in the database, and you should probably pass `dt` instead of a string value (unless this is a value for a future date, and then the best practices become more complicated).

Comment: If you had an array of age values, you could pivot the data before making an insert, which would make it less lines of code if not simpler.

Comment: Based on your comment this code is actually simple, and i cant make it less lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an array just to make your code looks simplier.

```
string[] table = {"Field1", "Field2", "Field3",...};
Control[] text = { textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text, ....};

    for(int i =0; i < table.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO lab(" + (table[i]) + ")";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + table[i], text[i]);
    }
```

Comment: At the end of the loop the `CommandText` will be: `INSERT INTO lab("Fieldn")`. Please fix your code.

Comment: @Andrei your answer is too close to what i want, but i made some differents in your code `string[] table = {"a", "b", "c"};
TextBox[] text = { age1, age2, age3};

    for(int i =0; i < table.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO lab(" + (table[i]) + ") VALUES ('" + text[i].Text + "')";
  
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }` i used this and i got this error `Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.`

Comment: @Aiman oh yeah, the semicolon at the end lol.